# Using MPI in subroutines

Tags: fortran, mpi, subroutine

I'm working on code that serially calls a subroutine (which in turn performs iterations) many times. I wish to parallelize the iterations inside the subroutine. The problem with mpi is that I'm only allowed to initialize it once. Hence, I cannot initialize it in my subroutine, which gets called multiple times. Can anyone suggest a way out of this?

My problem is roughly as outlined below:

```
program p

...

do i=1,10000
    call subroutine s(i)
end do

end program p

subroutine s(j)  

...

do i=1,10000
    ...
end do

end subroutine s
```

I wish to parallelize this process.

Thanks a lot. That helped! But let me re frame my question, 
Within the iterations of the main program, along with the subroutine s, I have to call another subroutine s2, (which doesn't need to be parallelized). I thought, it could be done this way:

```
  !initialize mpi

  do i=1:1000

  if rank!=0

  call s

  else call s2

  end if

  end do

  !finalize mpi
```

But the main problem here is, while the rest of the processes proceed slowly, process 0 will proceed quickly. (Something not desirable).So, is it possible to make process 0 wait after each iteration till the other process complete their iteration?

Comment: Please put your code in the correct mark-down format to improve readability

Comment: You call insert a barrier into the main loop: `call MPI_Barrier( MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror )`. All processes have to wait until the last one is at the barrier. But why would you want to do that? If one process is significantly slower than the others, there is probably something wrong with your load balancing!

Comment: I'm basically running a simulation over 10000 time steps.For each time step, the subroutine S has to run a 1000 step iteration, arrive at a value which is then used by subroutine S2, a less cumbersome subroutine, (doesn't need parallelization), before we move on to the next time step (out of the 10000). I can move in time only serially, (as the constants used in each iteration depend on the previous time steps). S basically solves the same set of equations for many particles, for the same time step.

Comment: If `s` and `s2` are completely different routines, calling `s2` instead of `s` will produce wrong results as process `0` will not participate in the calculations! So I would suggest something like `call s ; if (rank == 0) call s2`. If `s2` is much shorter, and its results are needed for the next iteration, I would suggest calling `s2` on every process (no further communication!).

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize and finalize MPI in the main program. Typically, you then define a load-balancing that is valid for the work in the subroutine.

Then you do your loop inside the subroutine in parallel and gather (reduce?) the results at the end of the subroutine so you have all information you need when the subroutine is called next.

This works the same way as it would with a loop in the main program (without calling the subroutine).

Here is a minimum example:

```
module testMod
  use mpi
  implicit none
!#include "mpif.h"
!===
contains
!===
  subroutine s(mysize, myrank, array)
    integer,intent(in)    :: mysize, myrank
    integer,intent(inout) :: array(:)
    integer               :: i, ierror

    ! Do stuff
    do i=1,size(array)
      ! Skip element that is not associated with the current process
      if ( mod(i,mysize) .ne. myrank ) cycle
      array(i) = array(i) + 1
    enddo ! i

    ! MPI Allreduce
    call MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, array, size(array), MPI_INTEGER, &
                       MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)
  end subroutine
end module

program mpiTest
  use testMod
  use mpi
  implicit none
!#include "mpif.h"

  integer :: mysize, myrank, ierror
  integer,parameter    :: ITER=100
  integer,parameter    :: arraySize=10
  integer :: work(arraySize)
  integer :: i

  ! MPI Initialization
  call MPI_Init(ierror)
  call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myrank, ierror)
  call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, mysize, ierror)

  work = 0
  do i=1,ITER
    call s(mysize, myrank, work)
  enddo

  if ( myrank .eq. 0 ) write(*,*) work

  ! MPI Finalize
  call MPI_Finalize(ierror)

end program
```